# Need help in clarifying relation of square root and logarithm to do a correct substitution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This might be so basic and obvious, but I am stuck on how to do substitution that involves logarithm and square root. 
If we have $$\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$$ and we do the following substitution $log_2n$ = m

How do we get $$2^{\frac{m}{2}}$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$ \log_2 n =m $$
$$ 2^{\log_2 n} =2^m $$
$$ n =2^m $$
Therefore 
$$ 
\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \sqrt{2^m} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor 2^{\frac{m}2} \right\rfloor 
$$

Comment: do we loose floor function?

Comment: @UserMoon, no we do not lose the floor function.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\log_2n=m \implies n=2^m$ and $\sqrt n = n^{1/2}$ but you lost the floor function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of the logarithm

$$
\log_b x = y \; \iff \; b^y = x
$$

You may also want to use the logarithmic rule

$$
\log_b x^z = z\log_bx
$$